# Using mysql in c programming

Tags: mysql, c, ubuntu, gcc

I installed ubuntu on a virtual machine. There, I installed mysql server `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` .This worked, because I could acces `mysql-u root -p password`

After that, I did : `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

When I compile this with

```
gcc version.c -o version  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

it works.

But when I compile this one from below

```
gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

I get some errors.

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
  MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

  if (con == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      exit(1);
  }

  if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root_pswd", 
          NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }  

  if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb")) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }

  mysql_close(con);
  exit(0);
}
```

Errors:

```
"Usage:: No such file or directory
[OPTIONS]: No such file or directory
Options:: No such file or directory
[-I/usr/include/mysql: No such file or directory
[-L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
.
.
.
unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
unrecognized command line option '--libs'
.
.
unrecognized command line option '--socket'
unrecognized command line option '--port' "
```

Can someone explain me what I did wrong,and how to fix it?

I just want to get some data from tables in a C program.

Comment: It would seem you got the command wrong when you are trying to compile as some commands get called with unexpected parameters, some of them being the output of some other command, this is not related to the other file but more likely to a mistake when editing the command.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you try to test again?

Comment: Works for me. Is that the exact command line you're using to compile it? As @CMoi says, the "errors" you get are actually the output from `mysql_config`.

Comment: I suspect you actually ran ``gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 `mysql_config` --cflags --libs`` rather than `gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 \`mysql_config --cflags --libs\``.

Comment: @icktoofay that is exactly what he did, post your answer.

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple sites. [Using mysql in C prorgramming](http://askubuntu.com/questions/564153/using-mysql-in-c-programming)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you actually ran

```
gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 `mysql_config` --cflags --libs
```

rather than

```
gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

That’s not going to work; `mysql_config`, if it doesn’t get any arguments, is going to print out a bunch of usage instructions, which will be passed to `gcc`, and then you’ll follow that with `--cflags --libs`, which `gcc` also doesn’t understand. `gcc` is severely confused and complains.

If you make sure those arguments get to `mysql_config` rather than `gcc`, everyone will be happy.

Comment: I always ran "gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 `mysql_config --cflags --libs`".
Thats not the problem...I still have those errors...

Comment: I mean,I used 
gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 'mysql_config --cflags --libs' 

with `instead of '